# List the files in Download directory of the Android phone

Tags: android, list, file, download

I am using the following code for trying to list the files in Download directory.

I build the apk, install it on my phone and then run it. I have files in both Internal memory/Download folder and External memory/Download folder when I view in File Browser of my phone, but the app does not display the file list. When I debug I find that the `listFiles()` function returns `null`.

Please let me know where I am doing wrong. The variable `state` has value mounted so the issue has nothing to do with the memory not being mounted.

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

private boolean isMediaAvailable() {

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


if (!isMediaAvailable()) {
        Utility.finishWithError(this,"Media Not Available");
    } else {

        String path =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ File.separator + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS;



        File file = new File(path);
        mRootPath = file.getAbsoluteFile().getPath();



        mFileNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        File filesInDirectory[] = file.listFiles();


        if (filesInDirectory != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i<filesInDirectory.length;i++) {
                    mFileNames.add(filesInDirectory[i].getName());
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is the value of file.getAbsolutePath()?  Please give also full paths of internal and external download folder. There is no internal download folder so im curious what you mean.

Comment: the file.getAbsolutePath returns /storage/sdcard/Download. By internal download folder I meant the Download folder that is shown under Internal Storage when I remove my SD Card out of the phone.

Comment: Well what is the path then? Shown under Internal Storage? Where is that shown?

Comment: /storage/sdcard/Download Is that the directory you go to with a file explorer and contains the files? You requested read external storage permission in manifest file?

Answer (score 10):

Use :

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
```

to get the downloaded directory,

and use [File.list()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#list%28%29) to get an array with the list of files in the directory.

Comment: files.list() returns null for me.Do you know what permissions required on 6.0 ?

Comment: YES you have to give storage permission to the application. Otherwise the list will be empty.

Comment: I already have added below 3 permissions : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: I can only get it to work If I add "android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" to the Application tag

Comment: It's not enough. The user has to give permission when opening the app at the first time (phone settings/applications/your app/permissions). If you give the permission in your manifest, it doesn't mean that the user will accept to give also the permission to the app (it's a question of security)...

Comment: This is deprecated in API 29