# How to get access to files in download directory in Android App

Tags: android, file-access

I am writing an android App. In the app I need access to the download directory \DOWNLOAD. I can read and write files within the app directory and I see the DOWNLOAD directory when I request the files within root directory.
But when I use

```
 File[] files = new File("\DOWNLOAD").listFiles();
```

the result is not a valid array but null.

I added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to the AndroidManifest.xml and I enabled the Storage permission on the phone.

What else must I do to get access to the files in download directory?

Kind regards,
Wolfgang

Comment: [Here is the link for the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281890/list-the-files-in-download-directory-of-the-android-phone/41424202)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that adding

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

is not sufficient. Now I **additionally** request this permission on runtime with following code:

```
String[] requiredPermissions = { Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE };    
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, requiredPermissions, 0);
```

and it works again :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution for the problem was to add also

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to the AndroidManifest.xml and to use

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).listFiles();
```

Thanks, for your help!

Comment: Note that this will not work by default for you on Android Q and is scheduled to be banned for all apps for Android R and beyond. Direct filesystem access to external storage is being substantially limited. Please consider switching to the Storage Access Framework (`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`).

Answer (score 0):

Add Storage read permission in manifest file

Refer: https://www.journaldev.com/9400/android-external-storage-read-write-save-file

https://gist.github.com/granoeste/5574148

Answer (score -3):

```
String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
File file = new File(home+"/Downloads/" + fileName + ".txt");
```